# Java Load image from jarfile

Tags: java, spring, email

I am trying to load an image from a jar file so that I can use it as an inline image for my emails but no matter what I try , it wont load for me

The code I am using is as follows

```
        MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
    message.setTo(toAddress);
    message.setFrom(fromAddress); // could be parameterized...
    message.setSubject(emailSubject);

    URL resource = this.getClass().getResource("emailTemplates/logo/logo.png");
    String fileStr = resource.getFile();
    File emailLogo = new File(fileStr);
    message.addInline("emailLogo", emailLogo);
```

Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not familiar with MimeMessageHelper, but you can't load a resource in a jar file using the `File` object. See if you can insert your image using the `resource` variable, as that URL points to the image you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the resource path does not begin with a `/` it is relative to the package of the class,

message.addInline("emailLogo", new ClassPathResource("/emailTemplates/logo/logo.png"));

A *resource* may stem from a jar or war or whatever, whereas *File* is bound to a file system.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepend the path with `/`. Your code should be:

```
URL resource = this.getClass().getResource("/emailTemplates/logo/logo.png");
String fileStr = resource.getFile();
File emailLogo = new File(fileStr);
```

Assuming you have a classpath and that, off of the classpath, you have a folder "emailTemplates" and inside of that you have a folder called "logo" with the image in it.

Comment: just to answer a post you made to a deleted comment. I gave the answer to Joop as it was the first reply I tried sorry and it looked tidy. I tried your answer too and it also worked well but could onyl give 1 answer sorry. No offence intended

Comment: None taken. I just wanted wanted to know if it was the way I answered, or the example I had given.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method  `addInline(String, org.springframework.core.io.Resource)` instead of the one that supports `File`.

So your code should be like the example below:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("emailTemplates/logo/logo.png");
message.addInline("emailLogo", new InputStreamResource(in));
```

It loads the image as `InputStream` and use an `InputStreamResource` to add to the email.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. This code is now in production and works fine:

```
URL imageUrl = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(/path/from/root/of/jar/pic.png);
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imageUrl);
ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
```

Edit: or why not a

```
message.addInline("myLogo", new ClassPathResource("img/mylogo.gif"));
```

Comment: How does he add the imgIcon to the email as an inline?

Comment: Thanks Alvin for seeing my typo.